# Error when running evalMetrics API on OutbreakLocation

Tags: json

I’m trying to hit the `https://api.c3.ai/covid/api/1/outbreaklocation/evalmetrics` API endpoint with a request body that looks like the following.

```
{
  "ids": ["Hubei_China"],
  "expressions":[
   "ConfirmedDeathsJHU"
  ],
  "interval":"DAY",
  "start":"2020-03-01",
  "end":"2020-03-30"
}
```

However, I get the error: `Invalid argument name "ids" for function OutbreakLocation.evalMetrics at JSON document at 2:11`

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Please stop adding meta tags to the site. See the discussion on [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394795)

Comment: Same for you, @bachr ^

Comment: @Cerbrus the tag `c3ai-datalake` is not a meta tag, it is specific to c3.ai datalake API https://c3.ai/products/c3-ai-covid-19-data-lake/ why do you think it's meta tag? (it is very specific)

Comment: [If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/). That tag requires additional tagging with a programming language and a method of accessing the API.

Comment: I see what you're saying, the thing it's a proprietary technology so users of this tag know that it is very specific, know the proprietary syntax while others will not. Here is the wiki of the tag, can you help to review it https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c3ai-datalake/info

Comment: Not everything needs a tag. If there are issues with the API itself, SO isn't the place for those questions, as they need to be asked to their support team, any way.

Comment: The issue doesn't appear to be with the API itself, but users' understanding and use of the api. This tag could theoretically operate as the only tag for the question. This seems like a legitimate tag to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request body of your API call looks correct, but you need to wrap it around a `spec` key like this:

```
{
  "spec": {
      "ids": ["Hubei_China"],
      "expressions":[
       "JHU_ConfirmedDeaths"
      ],
      "interval":"DAY",
      "start":"2020-03-01",
      "end":"2020-03-30"
    }
}
```